# proof $\frac{1}{k}+\ln(1-\frac{1}{k})=-\frac{1}{2k^{2}}+o(\frac{1}{k^{3}})$

Tags: real-analysis

I seek the following proof using Taylor's theorem:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{k}+\ln(1-\frac{1}{k})=-\frac{1}{2k^{2}}+o(\frac{1}{k^{3}})
\end{align}

Comment: The $o$ should be $\mathcal{O}$, otherwise it is not true. See Denis28's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

$$\ln(x+1)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\mathcal O\left(x^3\right)$$
and
and let $x=-1/k$, yielding
$$\ln(1-1/k)=-\frac1k-\frac1{2k^2}+\mathcal{O}(k^{-3})$$